# Highmaps - Change to mapbubble

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart, highmaps

I have been trying to change Highmaps chart to bubble by adding
type: 'mapbubble',  as below but failed
Is there any way to do it ? I dont know where went wrong

```
series: [{
  type: 'mapbubble',
  data: data,
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me to do that base on the code below

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/rich-info/)

```
   mapChart = Highcharts.mapChart('mapchart', {

        title: {
            text: 'Population history by country'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL/countries/1W?display=default">The World Bank</a>'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
         //  type: 'logarithmic',
            endOnTick: false,
            startOnTick: false,
            min: 50000
        },

        tooltip: {
            footerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">(Click for details)</span>'
        },

        series: [{
            data: data,
            mapData: mapData,
            joinBy: ['iso-a3', 'code3'],
            name: 'Current population',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            states: {
                select: {
                    color: '#a4edba',
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdot'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `point.value` with `point.z`

   ```
   data.push({
     name: countries[code3].name,
     code3: code3,
     z: value,
     year: year
   });
   ```
2. Set `chart.map` prop to mapData:

   ```
   chart: {
     map: mapData
   },
   ```
3. Create a new series which will be a background layer for bubbles.

   ```
   series: [{
     name: 'Countries',
     color: '#E0E0E0',
     enableMouseTracking: false
   },
   ```
4. Set the main series type to `mapbubble`

   ```
   {
     data: data,
     type: 'mapbubble',
     ...
   ```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/xf4tkec1/